# Rendering problem in "Basic Activity", Android Studio 3.1.4, API 28, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering

I am facing a rendering problem when I am trying to build an Android app which have a "Basic Activity" screen. I tried all the available solutions but nothing helps so far.

In case of "Blank Activity", when I am changing "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" to "Basic.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" in styles.xml, rendering is working properly. But this trick is not working when I am using "Basic Activity". Following is the configuration of my system:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Android Studio 3.1.4
- Android API 28

Following are the error messages:

- **Render problem**
  Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
- **Missing styles**
  Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.
- **Failed to instantiate one or more classes**
  The following classes could not be instantiated:
  - android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
  - android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
  Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListene

Following is my styles.xml file:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Following is my build.gradle(Module:app) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.root.myfirstapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Please help!

Thanks,
Sanjay Singh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some struggle, I found that issue is with API 28 (which is still not stable). I changed API 28 to 26 in my build.gradle(Module:app) file which finally looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    **compileSdkVersion 26**
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.root.jiocollect"
        minSdkVersion 21
        **targetSdkVersion 26**
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    **implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'**
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    **implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'**
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

After this everything was working.